# Best way to persist an ID String?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am curious as what the best way to persist a user ID is in VBA/Access.  The user ID would be used in various forms to track changes a user has made. In .net what I would do is to create a class that holds the user ID variable, or use my.system.settings.  Seeing as this is not an option, what are some ways or "the way" I can keep and hold a variable in memory or as a reference.  The thought that comes to mind is a "Settings" table, but im not sure if thats overkill, or if there is a known and better method.

Comment: wouldn't `Environ$("Username")` be sufficient?

Comment: Indeed I thought about that, but the current design is using numeric digits as a User ID and not the actual account name.

Comment: encode to a numeric value? to much hassle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persisting a value means, in Access, storing it in a database table. From your description I assume you mean persisting the value *during the current session*. In which case, once the value is obtained from a table, you could store it in a global variable, or as a property of an instance of a class that you have instantiated.

Another, Access specific, option is to set the value as the Caption for a hidden label on a form. This can either be on a main switchboard-form, that remains open throughout the session, or on a hidden form that is opened on start-up and, again, remains open throughout the session.

It is possible to create a registry-entry, but I would probably prefer to use a hidden-form. Whichever approach you take, it is important to ensure that the value remains intact throughout the session.

Comment: A slight variation, rather than adding a hidden label, is to set the `Tag` property of the main (switchboard) form to the user-id. `Me.Tag = 12345`. Then read it as `Forms!frmSwitchboard.Tag`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ID to persist only across that specific session, then a `Global` variable would probably suit you best.

If you want it to persist on a machine until changed, then using the registry would be better.

```
'SaveSetting appname, section, key, setting
SaveSetting "MyApp", "ID", "Value", "12345678"
'GetSetting(appname, section, key[, default])
CurrentID=GetSetting "MyApp","ID","Value" ' Add ,"DefaultValue" if you want a marker for if there is no value set  
'DeleteSetting appname, section[, key]
DeleteSetting "MyApp", "ID" ' add ,"Value" if you only want this specific key deleted
```